# Itext PDF writer, Is there any way to allow unicode subscript symbol in the pdf? (Without setTextRise)

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, pdf-generation, itext

I have been trying to create PDF files using Itext PDF writer. I have found that Superscript (0,4,5,6,7,8,9) and Subscript (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) are not allowed in the default font. Only Superscript 1,2,3 are allowed in PDF texts in the default setting.

A String in my PDF contains subscript and superscript characters, is there a way i can display them in PDF?

I searched and found:

1. setTextRise() method is used to change the displacement of the text with respect to the current line, I cannot use it as i don't know which characters are to super/sub scripted.
2. Is there a setting to change the encoding/font of the text to UTF-8, so that it allows all the unicode symbols?

Or some other way, because i have to show chemical symbols like H₂SO⁴, O₂ etc.

It'd be of great help, thanks!

Comment: You claim that UNICODE superscript characters aren't supported by iText. That allegation is wrong. iText supports many different fonts and if a font contains UNICODE and a specific glyph, iText allows you to use it. You should rephrase your question and ask: where can I find a *font* that contains superscript and subscript characters so that I can use them in combination with iText?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I edited the question. I am sorry, I was not claiming that IText does not support UNICODE, I just meant, I am unable to find support for a few in the default setting.

And yes as suggested by you, I'll check out different fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at the [`SubSuperScript`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/itext-building-blocks/chunk-examples#761-subsuperscript.java) example I wrote in answer to your question. I'm writing H₂SO⁴ like this:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font f = new Font(bf, 10);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("H\u2082SO\u2074", f);
document.add(p);
```

I've found the values of the specific characters on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

As you can see, iText is perfectly capable to show the special characters written in subscript or superscript: [sub_superscript.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/objects/cmp_sub_superscript.pdf)

The main problem I had when I wrote this example was finding a font that supported the specific glyphs. That's what I explained in my earlier comment. I ended up using a font called "Carbo Regular".

Comment: Hi, I tried a few more fonts as suggested by you. This has solved the problem for me. I'll post it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I could get to solve the issue by using this piece of code:

I had to register a new font "Arial Unicode MS"

```
FontFactory.register("Path/to/font/arial unicode ms.ttf","Arial Unicode MS");
```

Then while writing in the pdf i had to use this font with my string:

```
FontFactory.getFont("Arial Unicode MS",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```