# Java : Superscript not registering in PDF Exporter

Tags: java, pdf, itext, paragraph

Why is unicode not displayed in the PDF. I am using the following code. My system out is giving me the correct response but PDF does not have the superscript.

```
Document outputDoc
Paragraph pdfParagraph = new Paragraph();
pdfParagraph.add(new Chunk("A\u207B"));
outputDoc.add(pdfParagraph);
```

Comment: Use a font with an encoding that includes the superscript characters. The default font has a **WinAnsiEncoding** which does not.

Comment: Thank you @KJ. I also need a superscript plus \u207A.

Comment: @mkl can you refer me to the document that has the details for the font I need for superscripts. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24781270/1729265).